# modify socket.data attribute outside of io listener - socketio

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I've been creating a simple chat app, and I'm using the more recent socket.io version, specifically socket.io@4.4.1, which has access to socket.data, which is really helpful, but I'm stuck in trying to apply it. I looked through the docs, but the best I found was this:
[socket.data docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#:%7E:text=The%20data%20attribute%20is%20an%20arbitrary%20object%20that%20can%20be%20used%20to%20share%20information%20between%20Socket.IO%20servers%3A)

the code layout is like this:

```
function loginuser(socket, username,password){
if (authenticated()) {
    socket.data.loggedin = true
  }else{
    console.log("fail")
  }
}
```

and the io.on is like this:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
socket.data.loggedin = false

socket.on('login', function(data) {
console.log("logged in?: "+ JSON.stringify(socket.data.loggedin))
if(!socket.data.loggedin){
  loginuser(socket, data.username, data.password)
  //should return true here afterwards in socket.data.loggedin, but it doesn't
}else{
  console.log("logged in already")
}
});
```

so I was trying to pass socket through, which I *thought* would then allow me to change it across all of it, and not just the function. Has anyone done something simpler, or even let me know if this is possible? if not, what are some other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work for you.

```js
function loginuser(socket, username, password) {
  if (authenticated()) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.data.loggedin = false;

  socket.on('login', function(data) {
    if (socket.data.loggedin === false && (socket.data.loggedin = loginuser(socket, data.username, data.password)) === false) {
      console.log("Failed to log in.");
    } else {
      console.log("The user is logged in.");
    }
  });
});
```

In the above example, on a new connection, the default value of the `socket.data.loggedin` property is `false`.
If the socket emits the `login` event, you do the following:

1. Check if the `socket.data.loggedin` property's value equals to `false`. If it doesn't equal `false`, we jump to the `else` block, our user is logged in. If the condition is `false`, we go to the 2nd step.
2. We assign the `socket.data.loggedin` property's value to the return value of the `loginuser` function, and check if the newly assigned value equals `false`. If it's `false`, then the user is not logged in and it couldn't log in either. If the new value is `true`, we jump to the `else` block, because our user has logged in successfully.